# zend header already send problem

Tags: zend-framework

sometimes i got error when i include your class(AuthnetCim.class) in my controller.
the error is as below:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   ‘Zend_Controller_Response_Exception’
>   with message ‘Cannot send headers;
>   headers already sent in
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/public/include/AuthnetCIM.class.php,
>   line 1′ in
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:321
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
>   #1 /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(226):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect(‘/B4BPHP/public/…’,
>   302) #2
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(370):
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector->_redirect(‘/B4BPHP/public/…’)
>   #3 /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(453):
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector->setGotoUrl(‘index/login’, Array) #4
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(68
>   in
>   /home/newwebsi/public_html/B4BPHP/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php
>   on line 321

when i remove this class i do not get any error anywhere

Please, help me to resolve this error

Comment: Make sure that 'error_display' is off :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any characters before `<?php` in `AuthnetCIM.class.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Ouput is sent to the browser when the file AuthnetCIM.class.php is looked-up/included.

Check for spaces, BOM before the opening PHP tag, echoing/printing statements.

In other words check for anything that might be causing the script to output data.