# How to fix "Cannot send headers; headers already sent" in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

I am new to zend.I tried to create simple form having two fields using zend. When i click submit button got the following error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in D:\xampp\htdocs\study\quickstart\application\controllers\EmployeeController.php, line 35' in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php:282 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(300): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true) #1 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(727): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendHeaders() #2 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Front.php(984): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendResponse() #3 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #4 D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application.php(358): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\study\quickstart\public\index.php(25): Zend_Application->run() #6 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php  on line 282
```

I checked the following link,
[zend header already send problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045039/zend-header-already-send-problem)

I removed white spaces and gave close tag in all files, But still i am getting same error.

How to fix this error ?

Following shows **EmployeeController.php**:

```
<?php 
class EmployeeController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {

    }
    public function indexAction()
    {

      $form = new Default_Form_Empdetails();
       $this->view->form = $form;
        $request = $this->getRequest();
          $formData = $request->getPost();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {  
                $empName = $form->getValue('empName');
                $empAddress = $form->getValue('empAddress');
                $emp = new Default_Model_DBTable_Employee();
                $emp->addAlbum($empName, $empAddress);
              $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Kindly help me

Comment: What is in EmployeeController.php, line 35?

Comment: Remove white spaces after php closing tags(`?>`) in all files..

Comment: @NAVEED Yes removed it works. Thanks but before i removed white space above starting point of php tag

Comment: here, points to remember is as follows 
1.Need to remove white spaces before and after php tag
2.Need to close <?php ....?> tag properly

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It may be because of extra white spaces after php closing tag (`?>`) in some file.

Also read this Post:

[PHP development: why redirects don't work (headers already sent)](http://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/505/cpsid_50572.html)

> - Any HTML output, including the DOCTYPE declaration or any HTML tag,
>     including the head of the page
> - Extra whitespace before the opening PHP tag of the page, or outside the
>     PHP tags of an include file
> - Using print() or echo before calling header() or session_start()
> - Using virtual() to include files
> - Using the byte-order mark (BOM) at the beginning of a page

For example:

[image]

Comment: Just remove the closing tag if it is on the last line. It is not needed.